# how to generate glut .so file in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, dll, makefile

I would like to  generate glut `.so` file in Ubuntu. I've downloaded the [files](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php),  extracted them and opened the `readme`. This is the instructions for Linux

```
MAKEFILE GENERATION TO BUILD GLUT:                <-- IMPORTANT!

Use "mkmkfiles.sgi" to put Makefiles using the SGI Makefile conventions
in place.  Use "mkmkfiles.imake" to put Makefiles generated from
Imakefiles in place.  Run one of these two commands in this directory,
then do a "make".
```

I don't really understand `SGI Makefile`. I know Makefile though. Could you please guide me for generating the dll. In the folder, these are the files

```
adainclude     Imakefile     mkmkfiles.imake  README.fortran    README.man
CHANGES        include       mkmkfiles.sgi    README.glut2      README.mesa
FAQ.glut       lib           mkmkfiles.win    README.glut3      README.mui
Glut.cf        linux         NOTICE           README.ibm-shlib  README.win
glutdefs       Makefile      Portability.txt  README.inventor   README.xinput
glutmake.bat   Makefile.sgi  progs            README.irix6      test
glutwin32.mak  Makefile.win  README           README.irix64bit
IAFA-PACKAGE   man           README.ada       README.linux
```

### I've tried running `make` but getting errors and there is no `CMakeLists`. Thank you.

When I run `./mkmkfiles.sgi` or `mkmkfiles.imake`, I get this error

`bash: ./mkmkfiles.sgi: /bin/csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: What distro are you using? Glut is packaged in almost every distro I am aware of, and AFAIK you get no benefits from building it yourself.

Comment: if you think you should _build a dll in linux_, you're most probably better off with downloading glut package from your distro's packet repository instead.

Comment: Have you run either `mkmkfiles.shi` or `mkmkfiles.imake` before running `make` as it tells you to?

Comment: @MatthewRead, this is what I get `bash: ./mkmkfiles.imake: /bin/csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: @holgac, sorry my bad I was trying to say `.so`. You got the point though. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you need first to instal tcsh. With that installed, running mkmkfiles.imake will work and generate the required Makefile so you can build on Linux. Here is an old post asking pretty much the same question: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.lfs.general/17539